# Dynamic LINQ enumerable select

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following bool Variables:

```
    public bool bCompanyID { get; set; }
    public bool bTaxCode { get; set; }
    public bool bAccountCode { get; set; }
```

Depending on which ones are set to `true` I set the LINQ expression (this is an example where all three are **true**:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IP_DataRow> items = null;
items = _vm.Result_Error.Where(n => n.CompanyID == SelectedItem.CompanyID && n.TaxCode == SelectedItem.TaxCode && n.AccountCode == SelectedItem.AccountCode);
```

What I would like to do (rather than using multiple if statements) is to create this expression dynamically based on the user input.

Is something like this possible, or I simply have to use if statements?

EDIT:

Here is what came to my mind:

```
                items = _vm.Result_Error.Where(n => ((bCompanyID) ? (n.CompanyID == SelectedItem.CompanyID) : true) && 
                                                    ((bTaxCode) ? (n.TaxCode == SelectedItem.TaxCode) : true) &&
                                                    ((bAccountCode) ? (n.AccountCode == SelectedItem.AccountCode) : true));
```

Can I use the above mentioned expression?

Comment: It's certainly possible but for the sake of clarity I'd stick with the if statements.  No need to introduce complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you *can* combine then into one using something like this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IP_DataRow> items = null;
items = _vm.Result_Error.Where(n => (!bCompanyID    || n.CompanyID == SelectedItem.CompanyID)
                                 && (!bTaxCode      || n.TaxCode == SelectedItem.TaxCode)
                                 && (!bAccountCode  || n.AccountCode == SelectedItem.AccountCode));
```

but an `if` statement might be cleaner, especially since you can attach multiple where clauses to an existing query:

```
items = _vm.Result_Error.AsEnumerable();
if(bCompanyID)
    items = items.Where(n => n.CompanyID == SelectedItem.CompanyID);
if(bTaxCode)
    items = items.Where(n => n.TaxCode == SelectedItem.TaxCode);
if(bAccountCode)
    items = items.Where(n =>n.AccountCode == SelectedItem.AccountCode);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! Could I use my approach as well?

Comment: @RobertJ. Sure - they're logically equivalent.  Have you tried it?

Comment: It worked, yet I was not sure if this was a good way how to write LINQ

Answer (score 1):

You can combine some conditions with `if` statements:

```
var items = _vm.Result.Errors;
if (bCompanyID)
    items = items.Where(n => n.CompanyID == SelectedItem.CompanyID);

if (bTaxCode)
    items = items.Where(n => n.TaxCode == SelectedItem.TaxCode);

. . .
```

You can also create single LINQ expression that (as I think) is not so effective:

```
var items = from item in _vm.Result.Errors
            where !bCompanyID || item.CompanyID == SelectedItem.CompanyID
            where !bTaxCode || item.TaxCode == SelectedItem.TaxCode
            . . .
            select item;
```

In the second case the lazy evaluating of `&&` and `||` operators is used, so if `bCompanyID` is `false`, then right conditions will not evaluating.